# Video won't pause in cycle2-carousel by button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I want to pause a video within the cycle2-carousel slideshow via a Button. Somehow it does not work, although it works perfectly fine with a random placed video somewhere on the page. What am I missing here? Why is my second button/function unable to pause the video in the slidershow?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
function pausefirstvideo()
{
 document.getElementById('video1').pause();
}

function pausesecondvideo()
{
 document.getElementById('video2').pause();
}
```

```css
.slides
{
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.slides img
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.slides video
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>

<button id="pause1" onclick="javascript:pausefirstvideo();">PAUSE VIDEO1</button>
<button id="pause2" onclick="javascript:pausesecondvideo();">PAUSE VIDEO2</button>

<video id="video1" controls="controls"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>


<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-speed="500" data-cycle-timeout="8000" data-cycle-fx="carousel">
<div class="slides"><img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg"></div>
<div class="slides"><video id="video2" controls="controls"><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video></div></div>
```

Comment: You have typos, review this: `data-cycle-fx=carousel` it should be `data-cycle-fx="carousel"`. And also I'm wondering if this is correct:  `data-cycle-slides="> div"`

Comment: Fixed the carousel quotations, didnt really change anything, although thx for the hint. As for your second concern, this got me wondering at first as well, but this is the correct usage as stated in the cycle2 docs.